# Jetty websocket client connect to Stomp.js topic channel

Tags: websocket, client, jetty, spring-websocket

I have written a Spring Websocket server which is assessible from a browser via Stomp.js. I am now attempting to implement a Java client in order to connect my server to a secondary system. I am able to connect to the server using the following code

```
String destUri = "ws://localhost:8080/sample";
    WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
    SimpleEchoSocket socket = new SimpleEchoSocket();
    try {
        client.start();
        URI echoUri = new URI(destUri);
        ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
        client.connect(socket, echoUri, request);
        System.out.printf("Connecting to : %s%n", echoUri);
        socket.awaitClose(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
}
```

The connection is opened, and now I would like to connect to my topic /price-stream. This is achieved by stomp.js :

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/pricechannel1', renderPrice);
```

what is the equivalent subscribe method for my Jetty websocket client? I cant find anything in the documentation I have found on the net.

Additional info:

I am trying to implement the stockticker example [found here](https://github.com/gerrytan/stockticker) into another project. I can connect to the server through the provided [Stomp.js interface](https://github.com/gerrytan/stockticker/blob/master/src/main/webapp/resources/stomp.js) in a web browser. Now I am attempting to create a Java client for use within a Swing GUI using Jetty websocket-client to connect.

I need to connect to the price stream, but it seems I am missing some kind of configuration request to latch on as a destination for the topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, plain websocket clients (as the one provided by Jetty) support the websocket standard. STOMP is a protocol that sits on top of that transport.

Here, you'd need to implement your own STOMP client or interface an existing one with the websocket client you're using.

Spring 4.2 (to be published soon) includes a new STOMP client for this particular use case. See the [reference documentation of 4.2.RC2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-client).

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the direction of the 4.2 client! I have implemented the client , but I am stuck a little bit on how to provide a websocket container to the  StandardWebSocketClient constructor. I know I am close, could I please ask you to explain a little on how I should implement the container into my class?  I have tried to use the example here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-websocket/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/websocket/server/WebSocketServerTests.java but without much success. Thanks again!

Comment: all you need is described in the reference documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-client - you can use the StandardWebSocketClient or the Reactor11TcpStompClient.

Comment: The documentation is great and I have used the code samples there. But I keep getting an exception when I run thrown during WebSocketClient transport = new StandardWebSocketClient(); The Websocket client attempts to find a websocketContainer and I am unsure how to configure this. Sorry for repeated questions!

Comment: oh, ok. Do you have a servlet container on classpath, such as tomcat or jetty?

Comment: I didnt, and that was my problem. I have added org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles » websocket-ri-bundle  onto my classpath and i am connecting! Thank you for your advice!

Comment: hi, back again, sorry haha. I am connecting to the /ws url now. I was wondering how using the sockJsClient i can now connect to a topic channel? Using the Stomp client returns handshake error every time

Comment: to clarify, i keep getting HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 200 when i try to connect to priceticker-1.0/ws/ using stompClient . whereas SockJsClient connects to this URL fine

Comment: I guess you've configured SockJS for your "/ws" endpoint. This means this enpoint deals with multiple transports, including websocket. In that case you should try to connect to the websocket endpoint directly, which should be "/ws/websocket".
Or instead of using the StandardWebSocketClient, you can use the SockJSClient and totally mirror what you're doing on the client side (see here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-fallback-sockjs-client ).

Comment: appending /websocket  to the url worked, thanks so mcuh!